# «» resemble too much \ll \gg

Tags: symbols, punctuation, unicode, quoting

I am typesetting a translation of some ancient poetry book from another language (namely Finnish). In the text there are several quotes which uses the Guillemets (« and »).

Since I am using a UTF-8 encoded document (with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) in my text there are directly those symbols.

Upon rendering, however, the symbol closely resemble `\ll` and `\gg`, that is "much smaller than" and "much greater than".

Is there a way for me to obtain something more similar to « and » ?

Comment: A bit of off-topic: Have you ever thought about using the `csquotes` package? This would make your quotes configurable at one central place.

Comment: I guess that in my cases the quotes are complex. I am typesetting ancient poetry and often the quotes are very long (songs) and take many verses.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\begin{document}

«»

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
«»

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first line has *really* `\ll` and `\gg`, as the guillemets aren't available in the OT1 encoding. In the second line we use a T1-encoded font, which has the guillemets.

So write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\begin{document}

«»

\end{document}
```

and your guillemets will be OK.