# wider square bracket and narrower \gg\ll

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I have two independent (?) questions about alternative choices/fonts for math symbols:

(Q1) My manuscript has lots of formulae of the form

```
$| [ (stuff) ] |$
```

I can barely distinguish between the absolute value signs vs the square-brackets.  I tried using

```
\textbf[
```

which helps slightly but not much.  Is there a way to get a wider square-brackets --- i.e. where the "horizontal portion" is wider --- other than hacking with tikz?

(Q2) My manuscript also has lots of

```
$\gg\ll$
```

which looks ugly.  Is there a way to make these two signs --- only in this combo! --- narrower while keeping the height of the symbols?  The *width* of the signs in second output of the top answer for

[«» resemble too much \ll \gg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74484/resemble-too-much-ll-gg)

*as displayed on the screen* is what I have in mind (I don't need the "curved" signs but that's okay), but when I put in my paper the actually signs are too small.

THANKS!

Comment: For the first request $| [ (stuff) ] |$ the square bracket and the vertical line are they separated?

Comment: The `mathabx` font has shorter `\gg` and `\ll`.

Comment: tex has no control over character shapes. So your choice is to pick a different font (there are hundreds of possibilities, you have provided no example so we don't even know which font you are currently using) or to not use a character at all and draw the brackets with tikz or similar. For [ they are the only possibilities, for << you could also try not using the << character and using <\kern-4mu< or whatever negative space you like

Comment: @sebastiano:  In some cases the absolute value signs are right next to the square brackets.

Comment: @bernard:  Currently I use mathpazo + eulervm for my paper.  How do I use mathabx *just* for this \gg\ll combo?

Comment: @underflow: As it was a bit long to explain, I posted a small code to show how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to borrow symbols from `mathabx` without changing your maths fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{%
<-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
<10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxll}{\mathrel}{matha}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxgg}{\mathrel}{matha}{"22}

\begin{document}

\[ A \ll B \gg C \]%
\[ A \abxll B \abxgg C \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an improvement over the generic \gg\ll.  I will play with it.  Thanks!